# How to connect a array to the datalist element?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, html

LS,

I have created a array from a MYSQL table like this:

```
   $sqlNF="SELECT   FROM FEIHorse GROUP BY nf ";
$result=mysqli_query($dblink,$sqlNF);
$rawdata = array();
$i=0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $rawdata[] = $row;
    $i++;
}
```

The question is how to connect this array to an HTML input element to be used as a datalist

Comment: Iterate over `rawdata` and put values into `<datalist>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
  <input list="browsers" name="browser">
  <datalist id="browsers">
     <?php 
        foreach ($rawdata as $option) {
           echo '<option value=\''.$option.'\'>';
        }
     ?>
  </datalist>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```